# Displaying image on picture box using Web Camera Class c#

Tags: c#, camera

I have here a code snippet Web Camera Class the usage of this is to capture the image using camera source to picturebox object in .net programming such as C#.

```
     /* Usage: 
 * 
 * webCamera webCamera = new webCamera();
 * 
 * webCamera.StartPreview(PictureBoxName);
 * 
 * webCamera.StopPreview();
 * 
 * 
 * pBoxCaptured.Image = webCamera.CaptureImage();
 * 
 * 
 * 
 * */


using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using DevExpress.XtraEditors;



namespace EnrollmentSystem
{
    public class WebCamera
    {
        const int WM_CAP_START = 0x400;
        const int WS_CHILD = 0x40000000;

        const int WS_VISIBLE = 0x10000000;
        const int WM_CAP_DRIVER_CONNECT = WM_CAP_START + 10;
        const int WM_CAP_DRIVER_DISCONNECT = WM_CAP_START + 11;
        const int WM_CAP_EDIT_COPY = WM_CAP_START + 30;
        const int WM_CAP_SEQUENCE = WM_CAP_START + 62;

        const int WM_CAP_FILE_SAVEAS = WM_CAP_START + 23;
        const int WM_CAP_SET_SCALE = WM_CAP_START + 53;
        const int WM_CAP_SET_PREVIEWRATE = WM_CAP_START + 52;

        const int WM_CAP_SET_PREVIEW = WM_CAP_START + 50;
        const int SWP_NOMOVE = 0x2;
        const int SWP_NOSIZE = 1;
        const int SWP_NOZORDER = 0x4;

        const int HWND_BOTTOM = 1;
        //--The capGetDriverDescription function retrieves the version description of the capture driver--
        [DllImport("avicap32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true)]

        public static extern bool capGetDriverDescriptionA(short wDriverIndex, string lpszName, int cbName, string lpszVer, int cbVer);
        //--The capCreateCaptureWindow function creates a capture window--
        [DllImport("avicap32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true)]


        public static extern int capCreateCaptureWindowA(string lpszWindowName, int dwStyle, int x, int y, int nWidth, short nHeight, int hWnd, int nID);
        //--This function sends the specified message to a window or windows--
        [DllImport("user32", EntryPoint = "SendMessageA", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true)]


        public static extern int SendMessage(int hwnd, int Msg, int wParam, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.AsAny)] object lParam);
        //--Sets the position of the window relative to the screen buffer--
        [DllImport("user32", EntryPoint = "SetWindowPos", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true)]


        public static extern int SetWindowPos(int hwnd, int hWndInsertAfter, int x, int y, int cx, int cy, int wFlags);
        //--This function destroys the specified window--
        [DllImport("user32", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true)]


        public static extern bool DestroyWindow(int hndw);

        int VideoSource = 0;

        int hWnd;

        public bool StartPreview(PictureEdit _preview)
        {
            _preview.Properties.SizeMode = DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.PictureSizeMode.Zoom;
            try
            {
                hWnd = capCreateCaptureWindowA(Convert.ToString(VideoSource), WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD, 0, 0, 0, 0, Convert.ToInt32(_preview.Handle.ToString()), 0);
                Boolean temp = Convert.ToBoolean(SendMessage(hWnd, WM_CAP_DRIVER_CONNECT, VideoSource, 0));
                if (temp)
                {
                    //---set the preview scale---
                    SendMessage(hWnd, WM_CAP_SET_SCALE, Convert.ToInt32(true), 0);
                    //---set the preview rate (ms)---
                    SendMessage(hWnd, WM_CAP_SET_PREVIEWRATE, 30, 0);
                    //---start previewing the image---
                    SendMessage(hWnd, WM_CAP_SET_PREVIEW, Convert.ToInt32(true), 0);
                    //---resize window to fit in PictureBox control---
                    SetWindowPos(hWnd, HWND_BOTTOM, 0, 0, _preview.Width, _preview.Height, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOZORDER);

                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    DestroyWindow(hWnd);
                    MessageBox.Show("Device was not detected.");
                    return false;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                DestroyWindow(hWnd);
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
                return false;
            }
        }

        public void StopPreview()
        {
            try
            {
                SendMessage(hWnd, WM_CAP_DRIVER_DISCONNECT, VideoSource, 0);
                //VideoSource = 0;
                DestroyWindow(hWnd);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        public Image CaptureImage()
        {
            try
            {
                IDataObject data = default(IDataObject);
                Image bitMap = default(Image);

                //---copy the image to the clipboard---
                SendMessage(hWnd, WM_CAP_EDIT_COPY, 0, 0);

                //---retrieve the image from clipboard and convert it 
                // to the bitmap format
                data = Clipboard.GetDataObject();

                if (data.GetDataPresent(typeof(System.Drawing.Bitmap)))
                {
                    bitMap = (Image)data.GetData(typeof(System.Drawing.Bitmap));
                }

                return bitMap;

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Using the camera once it worked fine,but after closing the form then reopen it again. then use the camera source again it says that "Device was not detected."

Screenshot to make it clear.

[image: First Use]

[image: Second Use has error]

Device was not detected.
i think this class did not dispose on thread in proper way. anyone can help? thanks

Comment: Can you provide more of an explanation for "iv'e already use this class but the problem is when im restarting the application"? Did you run the application, it worked, then you closed it and immediately reopened it and it was no longer working? My guess here is that something is still using the video source, so when the message is sent the second time the resource is locked. Also try checking your processes to see if your suspicion is correct. Either way, we need more info.

Comment: exactly, you got what i mean. @JWiley but i did dispose using this function DestroyWindow(hWnd); i don't know why it wont stop in task manager processes.  any idea/solution. thanks

Comment: Are you threading any of this? Can you provide the code where you are disposing/ending threads?

Comment: Iv'e never use thread of this class. here's how i destroy/dispose.

public void StopPreview()
        {
            try
            {
                SendMessage(hWnd, WM_CAP_DRIVER_DISCONNECT, VideoSource, 0);
                //VideoSource = 0;
                DestroyWindow(hWnd);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }